# Find AD SamAccountName given a .csv containing only the emailaddress

Tags: powershell

I have a source .csv file with columnA `emailaddress` and columnB `Is this mailbox still in use?`.

I need to read the file, find the ADUser's `SamAccountName` based on the given `emailaddress` attribute and then where columnB = `NO` delete any AD accounts. If column B = `YES` update attributes.

The 2nd part, if `Yes` works great but I can't get the first part working as I'm not sure how to get and then pass the `SamAccountName` to the `Remove-ADUser` command.  Any suggestions would be great.

```
$Users = Import-Csv $SurveyResults
foreach ($user in $users) { 
    if ($($user."Is this mailbox still in use?") -eq "NO") {
        Get-ADUser -Filter "emailaddress -eq '$($user.emailaddress)'" -Property SamAccountName |
            Select-Object -Property emailaddres, samaccountname, wwWHomePage |
            Remove-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Confirm:$False
    }
    else {
        Get-ADUser -Filter "emailaddress -eq '$($user.emailaddress)'" -Properties * |
            Set-AdUser -replace @{wWWHomePage = "$($_.wWWHomePage) ACTIVE $(get-date -f yyyy-MM)"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, I would use the following:

Added Edit*

```
$Users = Import-Csv $SurveyResults
foreach ($user in $users) 
{
    $getADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "emailaddress -eq '$($user.emailaddress)'" -Properties *

    if ($($user."Is this mailbox still in use?") -eq "NO")
    {
        $getADUser | Remove-ADUser -Confirm:$false
    }
    else
    {        
        $getADUser | Set-AdUser -replace @{wWWHomePage="$($_.wWWHomePage) ACTIVE $(get-date -f yyyy-MM)"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion.   This script also worked.

Comment: @Drew If you don't plan on using any properties from the $getADUser variable, you can remove the property parameter as it's wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

[`Remove-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/remove-aduser?view=win10-ps) can take an ADUser object through the pipeline. If you’re sure that you will get only one ADUser object from the filter, or if you are certain that you want to remove all users that have the matching email address, then you can just pipe the result of `Get-ADUser` to `Remove-ADUser`:

```
$Users = Import-Csv $SurveyResults
foreach ($user in $users) { 
   if ($($user."Is this mailbox still in use?") -eq "NO") {
      Get-ADUser -Filter "emailaddress -eq '$($user.emailaddress)'" | Remove-ADUser -Confirm:$False
   } else {
      Get-ADUser -Filter "emailaddress -eq '$($user.emailaddress)'" -Properties * |
         Set-AdUser -replace @{wWWHomePage="$($_.wWWHomePage) ACTIVE $(get-date -f yyyy-MM)"}
   }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!   Thank you for the quick reply and that worked great.  I thought I read Remove-ADUser only took SamAccountName or DN for values but apparently it takes e-mail as well and worked great.   Thanks again!

Comment: You're misinterpreting - you were clearly filtering on email address for the `Get-ADUser` feeding your `Set-ADUser` (your 'yes' case), so you know that the filter was good. You were also passing the resulting object - _not any particular field!, the entire object_ - to `Set-ADUser`. The missing piece is that `Remove-ADUser`, _also_ allows you to pass an ADUser object through the pipeline. It doesn't matter whether you got it from checking the sAMAccountName, the email address, the DistinguishedName, or whatever; as long as it returns the ADUser object, you're good.

Comment: The above, incidentally, is the _fundamental_ difference between the DOS/Windows/CMD and UNIX/LINUX pipe, versus the PowerShell pipe - PowerShell pipes _objects_; DOS/Windows/CMD and the various UNIX/Linux shells pipe _text_. While the objects are much more complex, and _can_ cause confusion, once you understand the distinction, you'll find that the PowerShell pipe is far more powerful.

Comment: If this worked for you, it would be a good idea to Accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark below the upvote/downvote arrows - it marks the question as solved, and incidentally throws me a little more rep.